# Database's Table not showing any users but the database works fine

Tags: database

I've been working on my project for couple of weeks.
(Working with Visual studio 2022)
And I encountered this problem, When I'm creating a user in the web itself it works with the same password I created and all of that, but when I'm going into the database table to see all the username info, there are no users in the table at all.
If its a bug that can be solved without change in my code I would like to use your help.
If you need my code just ask for it and I will add what u need.

Thanks :).

```
string fileName = "SratimDB.mdf";
string tableName = "UsersTbl";
string sqlQuery = "select * from " + tableName + " where (username='" + username + "')";

DataTable table = Helper.ExecuteDataTable(fileName, sqlQuery);
int len = table.Rows.Count;
if (len > 0)
{
    msg += "user by that name already exists";
}
else
{
    string sqlInsert = "insert into " + tableName;
    sqlInsert += " (username, fName, lName, year,city,email,password, gender, prefix, phone, admin, more, movies, books, sports)";
    sqlInsert += " values (";
    sqlInsert += "N'" + username + "',";
    sqlInsert += "N'" + firstName + "',";
    sqlInsert += "N'" + lastName + "',";
    sqlInsert += "" + year + ",";//int
    sqlInsert += "N'" + city + "',";
    sqlInsert += "N'" + email + "',";
    sqlInsert += "'" + psswd + "',";
    sqlInsert += "'" + gender + "',";
    sqlInsert += "'" + prefix + "',";
    sqlInsert += "'" + phone + "',";
    sqlInsert += "'False' ,";//admin
    sqlInsert += "N'" + more + "',";

    if (hobby.Contains("movies"))
        sqlInsert += "'True' ,";//bool
    else
        sqlInsert += "'False' ,";

    if (hobby.Contains("books"))
        sqlInsert += "'True' ,";
    else
        sqlInsert += "'False' ,";

    if (hobby.Contains("sports"))
        sqlInsert += "'True' ";
    else
        sqlInsert += "'False' ";

    sqlInsert += ")";

    msg = msg + "<br>" + sqlInsert;
    Helper.DoQuery(fileName, sqlInsert);
    msg = msg + "<br> משתמש הוגדר בהצלחה<br>";
```

Comment: I thought it's just a bug in my visual studio that can be fixed.
Which of the code I need to provide ?

Comment: take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are trying to say that you are inserting user data on webpage and it will not inserted in database, However i have to check your code first!

Comment: Yes you are right.
I don't know which part of the code exactly you want me to add, so if you can be specific ill add whatever you need :).

Comment: Ok, Then you have to show me your insertion operation code, maybe i can help with that

Comment: You mean the register.aspx.cs?

Comment: Yeah that one but i don't have to check your entire code, you can show me just where the you are write the insertion operation

Comment: Added the code to the Question itself

Comment: Is that produced any error?

Comment: No
Also when I'm trying to create a user with the same name twice, it says that there is a user with that name already.
But still nothing shows in the users table

Comment: Are sure that you are checking that database where's you're trying to insert the records? There is no problem in your code but i think you're new in Visual Studio so it can happen you have to check your database wisely.

Comment: I am checking the correct database, I am new to Visual studio but I'm 100% sure that i checked the correct one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).